# AWS Elastic Beanstalk ebextensions configuration doesn't work when new instance gets spawned

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, supervisord, ebextensions

In my Laravel application, I have created a folder `.ebextensions` and it has the configuration to install [supervisor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#supervisor-configuration) in the EC2 instance.

When I deploy the application for the first time and the instance gets created, everything works fine. Supervisor gets installed.

But when the instance scales and a new EC2 gets spawned, it doesn't take the same configuration. I need to install supervisor manually on the newer instance.

Is there a way, where the newer instances would take the configuration from .ebextensions and run it in the similar way it did the first time?

This is the structure of the .ebextensions folder

```
.ebextensions
    - supervisor
        - setup.sh
        - supervisor_laravel.conf
        - supervisord.conf
    - supervisor.config
```

**setup.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Supervisor - starting setup"
. /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env

if [ ! -f /usr/bin/supervisord ]; then
    echo "installing supervisor"
    easy_install supervisor
else
    echo "supervisor already installed"
fi

if [ ! -d /etc/supervisor ]; then
    mkdir /etc/supervisor
    echo "create supervisor directory"
fi

if [ ! -d /etc/supervisor/conf.d ]; then
    mkdir /etc/supervisor/conf.d
    echo "create supervisor configs directory"
fi

. /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env && cat .ebextensions/supervisor/supervisord.conf > /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
. /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env && cat .ebextensions/supervisor/supervisord.conf > /etc/supervisord.conf
. /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env && cat .ebextensions/supervisor/supervisor_laravel.conf > /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisor_laravel.conf

if ps aux | grep "[/]usr/bin/supervisord"; then
    echo "supervisor is running"
else
    echo "starting supervisor"
    /usr/bin/supervisord
fi

/usr/bin/supervisorctl reread
/usr/bin/supervisorctl update

echo "Supervisor Running!"

yum -y install http://cbs.centos.org/kojifiles/packages/beanstalkd/1.9/3.el7/x86_64/beanstalkd-1.9-3.el7.x86_64.rpm

if ps aux | grep "[/]usr/bin/beanstalkd"; then
    echo "beanstalkd is running"
else
    echo "starting beanstalkd"
    /bin/systemctl start beanstalkd.service
fi

echo "Beanstalkd Running..."
```

**supervisor_laravel.conf**

```
[program:worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan queue:work --tries=3 --timeout=0
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
;user=forge
numprocs=3
redirect_stderr=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor_laravel.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor_laravel.out.log
```

**supervisor.conf**

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)

[supervisord]
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
logfile_maxbytes=50MB        ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
logfile_backups=10           ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
loglevel=info                ; (log level;default info; others: debug,warn,trace)
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
nodaemon=false               ; (start in foreground if true;default false)
minfds=1024                  ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024)
minprocs=200                 ; (min. avail process descriptors;default 200)
environment=SYMFONY_ENV=prod

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf

[inet_http_server]
port = 9000
username = user
password = pw
```

**supervisor.config**

```
container_commands:
    01_install_supervisor:
        command: ".ebextensions/supervisor/setup.sh"
```

Comment: What's inside .ebextensions and what are the content of the files alongside file names?

Comment: Anything in [instance logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html) for the autoscaled EC2 instances?

Comment: Also are the autoscaled instances running on the same OS? Thinking of path variations between Windows and Linux here

Comment: Right now I don't have the logs for it. Also, both the instances are running on the same OS.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer. But slightly in a different way.

Initially, I had all the files in .ebextensions folder, I moved some of the files into a different folder called "awsconfig" (The name doesn't matter), and moved some of the commands of setup.sh file to .platform/hooks/postdeploy and gave the permission as chmod +x to setup.sh

****Important****

AWS cleans up the .ebextensions folder after they are executed. I read that [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=173161)

I did this because supervisor was getting installed in the newer instance (the instance which gets created after scaling), but the configuration files weren't getting copied because there was no .ebextensions folder in the newer instance

To copy the  configuration files after the instance gets deployed, I used platform hooks postdeploy.

You can read about platform-hooks-postdeploy [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html)

This is the structure I have now

```
.ebextensions
    - supervisor
        - setup.sh
    - supervisor.config

.platform
    - hooks
        - postdeploy
            - setup.sh

awsconfig
    - supervisor
        - supervisor_laravel.conf
        - supervisord.conf
```

These are the changes in setup.php file which is split into two files in different folders

**.ebextensions/supervisor/setup.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Supervisor - starting setup"
. /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env

if [ ! -f /usr/bin/supervisord ]; then
    echo "installing supervisor"
    easy_install supervisor
else
    echo "supervisor already installed"
fi

if [ ! -d /etc/supervisor ]; then
    mkdir /etc/supervisor
    echo "create supervisor directory"
fi

if [ ! -d /etc/supervisor/conf.d ]; then
    mkdir /etc/supervisor/conf.d
    echo "create supervisor configs directory"
fi
```

**.platform/hooks/postdeploy/setup.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

. /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env && cat /var/www/html/awsconfig/supervisor/supervisord.conf > /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
. /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env && cat /var/www/html/awsconfig/supervisor/supervisord.conf > /etc/supervisord.conf
. /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env && cat /var/www/html/awsconfig/supervisor/supervisor_laravel.conf > /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisor_laravel.conf

if ps aux | grep "[/]usr/bin/supervisord"; then
    echo "supervisor is running"
else
    echo "starting supervisor"
    /usr/bin/supervisord
fi

/usr/bin/supervisorctl reread
/usr/bin/supervisorctl update

echo "Supervisor Running!"

yum -y install http://cbs.centos.org/kojifiles/packages/beanstalkd/1.9/3.el7/x86_64/beanstalkd-1.9-3.el7.x86_64.rpm

if ps aux | grep "[/]usr/bin/beanstalkd"; then
    echo "beanstalkd is running"
else
    echo "starting beanstalkd"
    /bin/systemctl start beanstalkd.service
fi

echo "Beanstalkd Running..."
```

The content of all other files remains the same as what I have posted in the question.